# 12.04 does not shows my windows partions nor my DVD ROM and aslo not my flash drive or phone memory card?

Tags: 12.04, mount, ntfs

I installed fresh a Ubuntu system on my computer but then it does not show the NTFS partitions, DVD-ROM and flash drive.

I have two HDD's. One is primary SATA (80 GB) and other is slave, an old IDE (40 GB). Neither shows up. What can I do to solve this problem?

Ubuntu 10.04 works fine but not this one.

Answer (score -2):

I learned this the hard way. Ubuntu needs all disks to be set to the third option, cable select. I had to set all my disks as cable select to get everything to load up correctly.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu system with IDE disks that are jumpered manually to master and slave, rather than using cable select. I have not had any problems. Can you provide any corroborating sources for this? And if so, has a [bug been reported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)? **On the other hand, if you have a single IDE drive, it must either be jumpered as primary or as cable select; not as slave. If that's what you mean, you may want to edit your answer to indicate this ...as that would probably be good advice.** But that wouldn't explain how a previous version of Ubuntu worked.

Comment: I have never had to use Cable Select.